# How to sprout 1 turtle within a group of patches

Tags: netlogo

If I assign a value to each patch, where most patches will share the same value to that attribute, is it possible to sprout just 1 turtle within that group of patches?  Where each group of patches will have only 1 turtle?  What would the syntax of that look like?

Doesn't matter which patch of the group gets the turtle, so long as that group of patches only has 1 turtle associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Just have those patches be part of a temporary group using the *let* command like this:

```
let targetedGroup patches with [someValue = true]
```

Then, just ask a certain number of those patches to do something using *n-of* like this:

```
ask n-of 1 targetedGroup [
    sprout 1 [
        set color blue]]
```

*A warning: if you ask more patches than there are in the group, you'll get an error. Try to use an *ifelse* statement to get around that if it is an issue for you.

Comment: That worked great.

Changed my mind though, is there a way to get the turtle to spawn in the middle most patch?  Would make the resulting world look better.

Comment: If I were doing that, I'd first

ask targetedGroup [(add x coordinates to a list, same for y, then average them)]

ask one-of targetedGroup with-min [abs (distance myself - {whatever the xy coordinate from the average is})] [sprout 1]